# IOS9 Contacts framework fails to update linked contact

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios9, contacts-framework

In AddressBook on device I have a record linked with Facebook contact record.
I fetch it into CNContact with CNContactFetchRequest with:

```
contactFetchRequest.mutableObjects = true  
contactFetchRequest.unifyResults = false
```

After getting, I modify it, then I trying to update it with:

```
let store = CNContactStore()  
let saveRequest = CNSaveRequest()  
if contact != nil {  
    mutableContact = contact!.mutableCopy() as! CNMutableContact  
    saveRequest.updateContact( mutableContact )  
} else {  
    mutableContact = CNMutableContact()  
    saveRequest.addContact( mutableContact, toContainerWithIdentifier:nil )  
}  
// Modify mutableContact  
mutableContact.jobTitle = "Worker";  

do {  
    // Will fails with error  
    try store.executeSaveRequest(saveRequest)  
} catch let error as NSError {  
    BCRLog(error)  
    self.isFailed = true  
} catch {  
    self.isFailed = true  
}
```

On execute executeSaveRequest, I caught an error:

> NSError with domain:CNErrorDomain, code:500 (witch is
>   CNErrorCodePolicyViolation), _userInfo: {"NSUnderlyingError" :
>   {"ABAddressBookErrorDomain" - code 0}} witch is
>   kABOperationNotPermittedByStoreError

The question: Is it possible to modify linked contact (not unified), and if it is, what i do wrong?

If I modifying not linked contact - all OK!

Comment: I have the same problem. contactStore.executeSaveRequest(saveRequest) is throwing an error. Someone help us!

Comment: Nothing seems to indicate that you can't modify a linked contact. Did you check the authorisation status of your contact store before trying to do the save request?

Answer (score 0):

I have this error when the Contacts app is configured to store contacts in an Exchange account. When I choose an iCloud account as a default it immediately saves a contact well. I can check what is set on your device in Settings -> Contacts -> Default Account